# Hibernate Set and sorting issue

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-annotations

in my entity I have currently such a mapping:

```
private Set<Sth> sths;
```

So when I use `criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(Sth.ID))`

then hibernate generates query with `order by id asc` but the elements in the set
are not sorted (I iterate through them to check) - I thought that in this case hibernate will use some kind of sorted set implementation (I don't want the data were always be sorted).

But if I use..

```
@OrderBy(Sth.ID)
private Set<Sth> sths;
```

Hibernate will generate exactly the same sql query but the data are sorted this time.
So my question is - is it a bug? I'm using hibernate 3.4.

Using OrderBy annotation is acceptable for me but maybe I wouldn't like to do sorting always by this property, so I would rather to give sorting instruction in criteria query than in annotation.

Any ideas? Does it work the same way in higher versions of hibernate?

Comment: Please, put the full query generated by hibernate

Comment: It's company production code. But it looks like this select <allproperties>
from FIRST_ENTITY this_ 
left outer join SECOND_ENTITY entity_ on this_.id=entity_.id
where <entitypropeties restrictions here>
order by entity_.id asc - the sql query is the same in both cases

Comment: See this link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-sorted

Comment: See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560590/hibernate-ordering-a-set.

Comment: I've seen it. but the problem is that I don't want to explicity set up sorting order in entity mapping, but rather in criteria or hql query.

Comment: The set is big so I would like to sort it on sql server side. and i don't want to sort it every time (sometimes my set don't have to be sorted, so I don't want to use sortedset as interface)

Answer (score 0):

Readed in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-sorted

**Associations can even be sorted by arbitrary criteria at runtime using a collection filter():**

```
sortedUsers = s.createFilter( group.getUsers(), "order by this.name" ).list();
```

where group.getUsers() is the result of your query.

Regards

Comment: Yes, but then I have to call this on every element of my previously returned List. Accordingly to your example I have a List<Group>. It's not what I exactly need. What i need is let's say "to have the possibility to conditionally turn on @OrderBy annotation functionality".